# Telrik grid extension for export

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to take the export of my telerik grid data.

My question is about [this page](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-mvc/grid/export-to-excel.aspx)

I found a way to export the grid data, but one thing which is not make me clear is that in controller  the action

```
Export(int page, string orderBy, string filter){
    GridModel model = Model().ToGridModel(page, 10, orderBy, string.Empty, filter);
    // remaining part
}
```

What is `GridModel`? Is it a built-in method? Is there any assembly reference is required to use it?

And if it is custom method then what do I have to write in it?

Answer (score 0):

The classes you are looking for are in the Telerik.Web.Mvc assembly.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your answer.
I want to know one more thing,
In that action method :

 Export(int page, string orderBy, string filter)
{
  GridModel model = Model().ToGridModel(page, 10, orderBy, string.Empty, filter); 
 // remaining part 
}

What is  Model(), what we have to write in it.
 I think it is not just retrieve all the data from table.